# Arabic pronounce symbol not showing correctly

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arabic

Im trying to put text with arabic letters, some of the text working correctly, and the others symbol is showing weirdly.

Some of the letters just font issue, i can still tolerate if it fix all the mistakenly displayed symbol.

I tried to change font, putting on string, custom font, but it does not work. Any ideas guys ?

i put the pull the text from string res currently.

here is the wrong letters.
[image]

here is the correct letters
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use custom font for your view..

For example [this](https://github.com/mobin-tabaran-intelligent-structure/MTTextView) view support TextView custom font from assets.

Comment: i tried already but its not working..maybe you can recommend some fonts ?

Comment: im sorry okay its now working but  i need to put it on text only, but it cannot work on string..thank you appreciate it very much

Comment: @HusaynIrfan it work on every string, what is your problem ?

Comment: tq very much i now understand it, thank you sir everything fine now.

Answer (score 0):

If you were wondering what encoding would be most efficient:

All Arabic characters can be encoded using a single UTF-16 code unit (2 bytes), but they may take either 2 or 3 UTF-8 code units (1 byte each), so if you were just encoding Arabic, UTF-16 would be a more space efficient option.